# Error al cargar archivo .js en la linea que especifica la base de datos

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, librería

Estoy empezando mis estudios de programación, como proyecto de estas semanas me han pedido que haga una base de datos con mongodb y había conseguido con la librería mongodb creando una función conectarme a la base de datos e insertar un documento. Pero al volver después de unos días y querer retomarlo donde lo había dejado me da error al intentar cargar el archivo .js con node. Así que no se que es lo que toque para que ya no funcione.

```
const mongo = require("mongodb");
const MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
const dbo = db.db('Libreria');

    const introduceCliente = (nombre, dni, telefono) => {
      MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true;
        if (err) throw err;
        
        dbo.collection("Clientes")
        .insertOne({ nombre: nombre, dni: dni, telefono: telefono });
        db.close();
        console.log("¡Cliente añadido!");
      });
    };
    
    introduceCliente('Angel', '0000000s', 666666666);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado después de muchas vueltas, había declarado la constante dbo fuera de la función. Una vez la cambie y la puse dentro de las {llaves} de MongoClient.connect funciono correctamente.